# Timestamps on the "active" tab should link to the change like on the front page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, recent-activity

On the front page, the modification timestamps link directly to the answer that was posted/edited. The timestamps on [the "active" tab for a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell) don't, however.

I often find myself checking on the active tabs on some of my favorite tags, as updates of the less-trafficked tags tend to get drowned on the front page. It would be quite nice if the timestamps here would have the same behavior as the ones on the front page, so I can easily get to the change.

[image: This should be a link]

In summary, I think this should be added because

- It's convenient.
- It's consistent with the behavior on the front page.
- It should be a pretty straightforward thing to add.

**EDIT:** I had originally posted this as a bug because I thought it used to work this way before. I'm not sure if that's the case, though, so I'm changing it to a feature request. Feel free to change it back if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with the next build, timestamps wherever we're showing `modified xxxx ago` for a question will now link to the last activity on that question...so the active tab will behave like the homepage.

This also brings other pages to be more consistent as well, for example this will affect the search active tab the same way.